# Using C++ library from a C++ plugin loaded by a C app

Tags: c++, c, dlopen, dlsym

I have a lib (.so) written in C++. If I do `nm mylib.so` I get `00000000000029a0 T _ZN4Bits7fromMemEPhl` (among others).

On the other hand, I have an app written in C, that loads some plugins which are written in C++ (dlopen, dlsym, etc).

If I try to use my lib from my c++ plugin I get `undefined symbol: _ZN4Bits7fromMemEPhl`. Why?

EDIT:

This is how I compile my plugins:

```
$(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.so: $(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.o
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@ -shared

$(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.o: $(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@ -g -Wall -std=c++11 -pedantic -lcpp-bitstring -fPIC -I.,-rpath=$(LIBS_DIR)/cpp-bitstring
```

And this is how I compile my main app:

```
$(TARGET): $(TARGET).o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ -g -Wall -std=gnu99 -ldl -lcrypto -Wl,--export-dynamic
```

EDIT:

The problem is clear. For some reason my library (cpp-bitstring) isn't linked to my plugin. Where is the piece of code that I'm missing?

Comment: How did you verify that your plugin was loaded correctly?

Comment: @jxh I placed a simple cout in the load and the "do_stuff" functions in my plugin code, and I saw that output in the console, so I assume the plugin loading/running works fine.

Comment: At what point does the `undefined symbol` message get printed?

Comment: @jxh When the core app tries to load the plugin (with dlopen) and I haven't commented the code that uses the lib I want to use. Note that as soon as I comment the code that uses the library, my plugin starts working again.

Comment: I just realized (after doing ldd my_plugin.so) that it's not linked to the library I want to use. Let me edit my question so you can see how am I compiling my plugins. @jxh

Comment: FYI, `CPP` is supposed to be the C-Pre-Processor. The C++ compiler is supposed to be `CXX`.

Comment: Is your `mylib` library mentioned anywhere in build scripts?

Comment: @frymode Yes, it's the -lcpp-bitstring in the 4th line of the part of my Makefile that I posted.

Comment: Is it displayed in `ldd plugin.so` output? Is cpp-bitstring just placed aside with plugin.so or registered in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: @frymode That is the problem I guess. `ldd myplugin.so` doesn't show `cpp-bitstring` as a linked library. The cpp-bitstring is just in another folder inside the project (but different from the plugins folder). No `LD_LIBRARY_LATH` anywhere.

Comment: Can it be linked with something different then? It seems you need at  least to specify library path for compiler: `-L$(LIBS_DIR)/cpp-bitstring`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your shared object, you have to provide the library dependencies if you want the libraries picked up when loading the plugin dynamically.

Here is a simple Makefile:

```
plugin.o:       CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
main:   LDFLAGS += -ldl
all:    main plugin.so

plugin.so:      plugin.o
        $(CXX) $^ -o $@ -shared -lreadline
```

The `main.c` file looks like:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <assert.h>

int
main (void)
{
    void *p = dlopen("./plugin.so", RTLD_NOW);
    assert(p);
    void (*do_stuff)(void) = dlsym(p, "do_stuff");
    assert(do_stuff);
    do_stuff();
    dlclose(p);
    return 0;
}
```

And the `plugin.cpp` file looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>

extern "C" void do_stuff (void) {
    while (char *s = readline("> ")) {
        std::cout << "- " << s << std::endl;
        free(s);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I tried `$(CXX) $^ -o $@ -shared -lcpp-bitstring`, but ld complain about not being able to find the library. How can I tell `ld` where the library is? Appending `,-rpath=$(LIBS_DIR)` doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Precede the `-lcpp-bitstring` with `-L/where/the/library/is`.

Comment: I'm almost there. `$(CXX) $^ -o $@ -shared -L$(LIBS_DIR)/cpp-bitstring -lcpp-bitstring` makes `ldd plugin.so` to show  that i'ts linked to `libcpp-bitstring`, but it says it can't find it. How can I check where is it looking it for?

Comment: You can either add `/where/the/library/is` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or you can add `-Wl,-R/where/the/library/is` to the link line (right after `-L/where/the/library/is`).

Comment: That worked. But what am I doing exactly with the -Wl and the -R args? Well, -R, probably is saying the exact path where to look for the lib, but what is -Wl doing?

Comment: `-Wl,` passes the arguments to the linker. The linker treats `-R /path` as an alias of `-rpath=/path` , but that is a compatibility thing. `-R file` usually means "use file as a symbol table".